# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath only recognize taps with two fingers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm attempting to present a `UIAlertController` when a `UITableViewCell` is selected. I have checked all the storyboard-related issues such as `Selection: Single Selection` and even set `tableView.allowsSelection = true` at the top of `viewDidLoad()`. I also checked the issues of using `didDeselect` as opposed to `didSelect`.

Oddly enough the cell only selects when I tap it with two fingers at the same time or when I press it for a longer period of time (about 2s and then release). Is this a known problem?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Tap registered")
}
```

Any amount of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any more relevant code you could show us? Any tap gestures that you implemented?

Comment: Are you using any gesture recognizers?

Comment: This particular view controller doesn't have any gesture recognizers implemented.

Comment: I am experiencing this as well. very odd.

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem but saw other posts noting that a UIGesture Recognizer attached to parent view was the problem. I had done just that. The Gesture recognizer was used to dismiss the keyboard. So for what it is worth make sure you take care when using an UIGestureRecognizer in a UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question issue for a long time, so I'm gonna leave my solution here for others who face this problem, as I use this method and it works fine.
Here are my codes :

**For tableViewCell**

First, declare a variable, we check null to avoid crash on the table

```
var tapOnCell: (() -> Void)?
```

Then inside awakeFromNib block, so here we create an UITapGestureRecognizer for tap action, the gesture will require us to tap 1 time on cell.

```
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnContenView))
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    contentView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Then create a function like below

```
@objc func tapOnContenView() {
    if let tapOnCell = self.tapOnCell {
        tapOnCell()
    }
}
```

So we finish here on tableViewCell now it's time for tableView

**For tableView (UITableViewDataSource)**

call function that we create on tableViewCell and use it here

```
cell.tapOnCell = {
        self.tapOnSingleCell(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
```

but first, we need to create the function for action that you want to perform when you click on the cell, for me, I want to go to another viewController when I click the cell.

```
func tapOnSingleCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let jobDetail: JobDetailViewController = 
JobDetailViewController.newInstance(storyboardName: .jobSearch)
    let job = self.relatedList[indexPath.row]
}
```

I hope this solution help you as well as it help me, cheer.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use:

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

**Code:**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(yourFunctionOnTap)];
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```